# Create batching request for MS GraphApi

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, batch-processing

I want to optimize number of API calls to MS GraphAPI.

So, what I need is to get number of events from my calendar and to sync with graphAPI Calendar events.

Number can vary from 0-1000 (approx.)

How can I call it in a right manner?

Here is the example of creating batch request:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ExecuteBatchRequest(IEnumerable<Func<Task<string>>> batchRequests)
    {
        var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

        var requestIndex = 1;
        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var requestFunc in batchRequests)
        {
            var request = await requestFunc.Invoke();
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, request);
            batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(httpRequestMessage, requestIndex.ToString());
            requestIndex++;
        }

        var batchResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

        foreach (var responseFunc in batchRequests)
        {
            var response = await batchResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<string>(requestIndex.ToString());
            result.Add(response.Result);
            requestIndex++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Do you have some idea for better code?

Comment: Here is the code sample to get you started and guide you on this - Here is the code sample to get you started https://github.com/Azure-Samples/graphapi-batching

Answer (score 0):

If you have **`0-1000`** events in your calendar you can create a class with the **`JSON ID format`**  and then call it in your Azure Functions code like below:-

I have replicated the same scenario with Microsoft Graph API users as I have multiple users in my Directory:-

***My Azure Functions Code:-***

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        // Add other properties as needed based on the Graph API response
    }

    public class GraphApiResponse<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
        public string Context { get; set; }

        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var token = await GetAccessToken("xxxxxxaf9038592395", "xxxxx26a31435cb", "xxxxxa2Hr3wUzLFlwpK4b4M");
            var users = await GetUsers(token);

            return new OkObjectResult(users);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }), default);
            return result.Token;
        }

        private static async Task<List<User>> GetUsers(string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/")
            };

            string URI = $"users";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphApiResponse<List<User>>>(content);

                if (responseWrapper != null)
                {
                    return responseWrapper.Value;
                }
            }

            // Handle the failure case or empty response
            return new List<User>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***For Calendar Event:-***

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Event
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        // Add other properties as needed based on the Graph API response for events
    }

    public class GraphApiResponse<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
        public string Context { get; set; }

        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var userId = "UserId"; // Replace with the actual user ID
            var calendarId = "CalendarId"; // Replace with the actual calendar ID
            var token = await GetAccessToken("YourTenantId", "YourClientId", "YourClientSecret");
            var events = await GetEvents(token, userId, calendarId);

            return new OkObjectResult(events);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }), default);
            return result.Token;
        }

        private static async Task<List<Event>> GetEvents(string token, string userId, string calendarId)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/")
            };

            string URI = $"users/{userId}/calendars/{calendarId}/events";

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URI);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var responseWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphApiResponse<List<Event>>>(content);

                if (responseWrapper != null)
                {
                    return responseWrapper.Value;
                }
            }

            // Handle the failure case or empty response
            return new List<Event>();
        }
    }
}
```

***Approach 2:-***

You can utilize the code below to try batching in the Azure Function to call Microsoft Graph API and implement it for your Get Calendars event API:-

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var token = await GetAccessToken("83331f4e-7f45-4ce4-99ed-af9038592395", "c0c952e9-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb", "Fex8Q~i_cgyujE4aJ2dFkBa2Hr3wUzLFlwpK4b4M");
            var results = await GetResults(token);

            return new OkObjectResult(results);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }), default);
            return result.Token;
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetResults(string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/")
            };

            var batchRequests = new List<HttpRequestMessage>();
            const int numberOfRequests = 5; // Change this number based on your requirements

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
            {
                string requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{i}"; // Use absolute URI for each request

                var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                batchRequests.Add(httpRequestMessage);
            }

            var batchResponses = await SendBatchRequest(httpClient, batchRequests);

            // Process batch responses here (if needed)
            // For example, concatenate or structure the results in a specific way
            var aggregatedResult = string.Join("\n", batchResponses);

            return aggregatedResult;
        }

        private static async Task<List<string>> SendBatchRequest(HttpClient httpClient, List<HttpRequestMessage> batchRequests)
        {
            var batchEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch";

            var batchContent = new MultipartContent("mixed");
            foreach (var request in batchRequests)
            {
                var content = new HttpMessageContent(request);
                batchContent.Add(content);
            }

            var batchResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(batchEndpoint, batchContent);

            var batchResponses = new List<string>();
            if (batchResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = await batchResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Deserialize the batch response content to extract individual responses
                var batchResponseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseContent);

                foreach (var responseItem in batchResponseData)
                {
                    // Extract and handle individual batch responses
                    var responseData = responseItem.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
                    var responseBody = responseData["body"].ToString(); // Extract the response body
                    batchResponses.Add(responseBody);
                }
            }

            return batchResponses;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!
But Im trying to use built-in htpClient from GraphSDK?
Also Im trying to do authorization withPKCE (auth code)

Comment: Okay, Try referring this Document -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp and Refer the samples here for Auth code flow- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#web-applications