# Function app access control based on resource group

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app deployed in a resource group on Azure, when I send a request via backend it block the body of the request and when I send it via postman it is fine. I tired the same function app in another resource group and that is working fine. I was wondering if there is any policies or access rules which is applied based on a resource group that my function app is located?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's type of backend? What tells you the body is being blocked? any error messages or logs?

Answer (score 0):

This is a transient error on Azure Function app. In order to resolve this error, Check your Function Logs and see if there's any issue with your Function App by visiting Diagnose and Solve Problem:-

**Log Stream:-**

[image]

**Diagnose and solve problems:-**

***Availability and Performance > Function Executions and Errors***

[image]

***Application Insights:-***

[image]

Sometimes due to the region constraints, Some Function app fails to retrieve the Request from backend ARM. Thus re-deploying Function app tends to resolve the issue.

In-case you want to check if any policy is imposed on the Resource group, You can delete the Policy or Exclude your resource group from the policy by visiting here:-

**Delete Policy:-**

[image]

**Exclude Policy:-**

[image]

Make sure you have implemented the `Post Body` in your Function code itself. Reference [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665158/create-batching-request-for-ms-graphapi/77677487#).

**Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var token = await GetAccessToken("xxxxxxf9038592395", "xxxxx435cb", "xxxxxNPF~r3dBgcLX");
            var results = await CreateNewUser(token);

            return new OkObjectResult(results);
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
        {
            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientKey);
            var result = await credentials.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }), default);
            return result.Token;
        }

        private static async Task<string> CreateNewUser(string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/")
            };

            string URI = "users";

            var newUser = new
            {
                accountEnabled = true,
                displayName = "Adele Vance",
                mailNickname = "AdeleV",
                userPrincipalName = "msgraphuserhshs@sid24desaioutlook.onmicrosoft.com",
                passwordProfile = new
                {
                    forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    password = "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
                }
            };

            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newUser);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(URI, content);

            var httpResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return httpResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented Post body of Microsoft Graph API in my code itself. And my function ran successfully like below:-

[image]